# Connecting to remote gremlin-server using gremlin-python with uname and password

Tags: gremlin, janusgraph

I am trying to connect to a remote gremlin server which requires uname/password authentication over ssl using `gremlin_python`. This is a snippet of the code I am using:

```
conf = yaml.load(stream, Loader=yaml.SafeLoader)
print(conf) 
g = traversal().withRemote(DriverRemoteConnection(**conf))
```

The contents of the conf dict is:

```
{'url': 'wss://my-url.com:port', 'username': 'admin', 'password': '**', 'traversal_source': 'graph_traversal'}
```

I am able to connect to the same server from gremlin console using a conf/my.properties file that looks like

```
  hosts: [my-url.com]
  port: port
  username: admin
  password: *
  connectionPool: { enableSsl: true }
  serializer: { className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GryoMessageSerializerV1d0, config: { serializeResultToString: true }}
```

My attempts to connect from python is resulting in a `E   tornado.httpclient.HTTPError: HTTP 502: Bad Gateway`. I know that my connection url itself is correct, I am able to connect from the gremlin-console as well as send scripts over https. I have been trying to look at the code [here](https://github.com/apache/tinkerpop/blob/master/gremlin-python/src/main/jython/gremlin_python/driver/driver_remote_connection.py) to figure out what is going wrong.

[EDIT:] After looking at this a little deeper, I figured out that you can authenticate with the `wss server` with an auth token in the header. I was able to test this out directly with `websockets`. Is there any way I can pass along a parameter in the header when I open a `DriverRemoteConnection` for gremlin_python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `{{ end_point }}`, `{{ username }}`, `{{ password }}` as your real value:

```
from tornado import httpclient

my_req = httpclient.HTTPRequest('wss://{{ end_point }}:8182/gremlin', headers={"Authorization": "Token AZX ..."})

DriverRemoteConnection(my_req, 'g', username="{{ username }}", password="{{ password }}")
```

Comment: This is pretty much what I am trying now. Is there an option to pass http header parameters to the wss server through the `DriverRemoteConnection`? The graph service I am using is expecting a token to authenticate.

Comment: @MaxArbiter what http header you want to pass?

Comment: Thanks for looking in. I was hoping to pass `header='{Authorization: Token AZX....}'` I was able to authenticate using this when I tested directly with python `websocket` s

Comment: @MaxArbiter the first parameter of DriverRemoteConnection.__init__ could be an instance of HTTPRequest, refer to the updated answer

Comment: That seems to have done the trick w00t w00t. Thank you very much.